# Implementing a delegate that is triggered for every frame in a locally stored video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation

How can I implement a delegate that is triggered for every frame in a locally stored video? I tried `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` but it isn't working for locally stored videos. Is there any other to do this, or can I use a virtual `AVCaptureDevice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVCapture_**_** methods are all meant for camera-type things, which a movie file on disk most certainly is not.

I suspect what you are *really* looking for is something like the ["`AVPlayerItemVideoOutput`" class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItemVideoOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012229), which came in with iOS 6.0.

[While it has a delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItemOutputPullDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012230), I haven't yet used this new object or protocol and I don't know if the delegate methods such as "`outputSequenceWasFlushed`" will actually be useful for your purposes). One thing about the `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` class is that it like you can get at the pixel buffer for those items (i.e. which, for movies, would be frames).

Comment: The AVPlayerItemVideoOutput only provide us pixel buffer at certain CMTime.
I want that for every frame it throughs or triggers a method that which return pixel data of that frame. Somewhat exactly like captureOutputSampleBuffer.
Would you provide me any working code sample, that may help me for better understanding?

Comment: I haven't used this new class yet and I didn't see anything obvious when I checked Apple's sample code archive.  [I do see a potentially useful related question here on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232072/cant-have-avassetimagegenerator-give-me-all-the-frames-of-a-movie), which shows how to get each and every frame of a movie file.  Maybe that might help you out?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look on these:
https://ar.qualcomm.at/support_file/download/iOS/videoplayback%20sample%20app/vuforia-videoplayback-ios-1-0-2.zip

It implement something like you want it. It relies on an *AVAssetReader* you can use the *AVAssetReaderOutput -> copyNextSampleBuffer* method.

You can setup a timer for every frame played based on the frame rate of the video asset, in the timer you can retrieve the aforementioned *CMSampleBufferRef* retrieved by *copyNextSampleBuffer* , also it's available from iOS4.x