# generateCGImagesAsynchronously produces duplicate images according to actualTime

Tags: ios, swift, cgimage, avasset, avassetimagegenerator

I am able to get the frames from a video using `AVAssetImageGenerator`, and I do so using `generateCGImagesAsynchronously`. Whenever the result succeeds, I print the `requestedTime` in seconds as well as the `actualTime` for that image. In the end, however, two generated images are the same and have the same `actualTimes` even though my step value and frames for times are evenly spaced out.

Here is a snippet of my printed requested and actual times in seconds for each image:

```
Requested: 0.9666666666666667
Actual: 0.9666666666666667

Requested: 1.0
Actual: 1.0

Requested: 1.0333333333333334
Actual: 1.0333333333333334

Requested: 1.0666666666666667
Actual: 1.0666666666666667

Requested: 1.1
Actual: 1.1

Requested: 1.1333333333333333
Actual: 1.1

Requested: 1.1666666666666667
Actual: 1.135
```

It seems to be going fine until the frame corresponding to 1.1 seconds in the video is generated, which results in two of the same images and the `actualTime` to be delayed for the rest of the process.

I've already tried adjusting the way in which I compute the frames that should be generated, but it seems to be correct. I am using frames per second and multiplying that by the video duration to figure out how many frames I need to have in total, and I'm dividing the total duration by the sample counts to make sure cgImages are generated evenly.

```
let videoDuration = asset.duration
print("video duration: \(videoDuration.seconds)")
let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
let fps = videoTrack.nominalFrameRate
var frameForTimes = [NSValue]()
let sampleCounts = Int(videoDuration.seconds * Double(fps))
let totalTimeLength = Int(videoDuration.seconds * Double(videoDuration.timescale))
let step = totalTimeLength / sampleCounts
for i in 0 ..< sampleCounts {
     let cmTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(i * step), timescale: Int32(videoDuration.timescale))
     frameForTimes.append(NSValue(time: cmTime))
}
```

and the way in which I create images ([see this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66332/)):

```
imageGenerator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: timeValues) { (requestedTime, cgImage, actualTime, result, error) in
     if let cgImage = cgImage {
          print("Requested: \(requestedTime.seconds), Actual: \(actualTime.seconds)")
          let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
          // scale image if you want
          frames.append(image)
     }
}
```

I also set tolerance to zero before calling `generateCGImages`:

```
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = CMTime.zero
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = CMTime.zero
```

I expected the actual times to be consistent with the requested times, and for each image produced to be different. Looking through the images, there is always a duplicate regardless of the video being tested, and it normally occurs towards the middle to end.

**Edit:**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245781/avassetimagegenerator-returns-sometimes-same-image-from-2-successive-frames), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525253/generate-images-from-avassetimagegenerator-gives-same-image-duplicates-for-diffe?rq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232072/cant-have-avassetimagegenerator-give-me-all-the-frames-of-a-movie) which mention the same problem but I've had no success with any of them.